# Embed DLLs in Windows Form (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed third party DLLs to a windows form.
The third party library can be found [here](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui) (Dennis Magno - MetroFramework-Modern-UI)

Everything is working correctly if I run the application from the bin folder where/when the MetroFramework DLLs are present. However I cannot embed them into my exe.

I have try a number of things:

1. I followed this [tutorial](http://adamthetech.com/2011/06/embed-dll-files-within-an-exe-c-sharp-winforms/) (manually set DLLs to embedded
   resources +    code handler)
2. I tried to use Costura.Fodi (installed from Nuget)
3. I had a look at ILMerge

I always get the same error on lauching the application:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MetroFramework, Version=1.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f91a84759bf584a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

For reference here is the code I used as handler for the first option I tried:

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) =>
        {
            String thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            System.Reflection.AssemblyName embeddedAssembly = 
                                                           new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
            String resourceName = thisExe + "." + embeddedAssembly.Name + ".dll";

            using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        };
```

**EDIT 1:**
After the comments pointed me in the right direction, I changed my code to look like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       //Embed extra DLLs defined as 'embeddedResources' (MetroFramework)
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;
       realMain();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] 
    private static void realMain()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }


    public static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        String thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        System.Reflection.AssemblyName embeddedAssembly =
                                                       new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
        String resourceName = thisExe + ".libs." + embeddedAssembly.Name + ".dll";
        // String resourceName = embeddedAssembly.Name + ".dll";
        var debugStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        string[] names = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

        using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the AssemblyResolve event before everything else, and calling the rest of the code from a different method (realMain()) solved the issue.

But now the same exception is being thrown from Models.Designer.cs (I am using .NET 3.5 and EF v1). The following code now leads to the exception:

```
 public List<MyObj> selectGalLocation(string num) 
    {
        using (My_Entities db = new My_Entities())
        {
            //some PCs may be used for more than one stage/station....
            return db.MyObj.Include("L_Lookup").Include("P_DB").Where(x => x.no == num).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The code that actually throws the exception is auto-generated:

```
 public partial class CTRS_Entities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new My_Entities object using the connection string found in the 'My_Entities ' section of the application configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    public My_Entities() : 
            base("name=My_Entities ", "My_Entities ")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
```

I do not understand why this code, that is unrelated to the MetroFramework as far as I can tell, throws the exception. There is obviously something I do not understand correctly...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you check if the `AssemblyResolve` event is being triggered prior to the usage of the Assembly?

Comment: In all likelihood you subscribed the AssemblyResolve event too late.  It must be done before the just-in-time compiler needs the assembly.  That is a problem when your startup form uses the metro framework, it is used your Main() entrypoint.  Chicken-and-egg.  You need to *only* subscribe the event and call another method that you add, say "RealMain".  Give it the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute so it still works in the Release build.

Comment: @HansPassant: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: vendettamit, @HansPassant thanks for your comments they pointed me in the right direction. Only subscribing to the event in Main() and putting the rest of the code in a RealMain() method solved this issue. It lead me to another problem though. As far as I can tell the assembly is loaded, but when the 'real code' start, a call to EntityFramework falls over on the same error, saying it cannot find the file. I may post a separate question for this...